# Constructing a Method ID on Solidity

Tags: encoding, cryptography, solidity, smartcontracts, metamask

Good Afternoon Everybody! Based off the example on [the official website.](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/develop/abi-spec.html#examples) The example they provided was:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.9.0;

contract Foo {
    function bar(bytes3[2] memory) public pure {}
    function baz(uint32 x, bool y) public pure returns (bool r) { r = x > 32 || y; }
    function sam(bytes memory, bool, uint[] memory) public pure {}
}
```

In Following the example; I Understand to take the method name along with the parameters in its ASCII form and you should be able to produce `0xcdcd77c0`(After taking its first 4 Bytes)

So in my quest to understand the process so that I may recreate it programmatically, I found an online [Keccak-256 Converter](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/keccak_256.html) and it produced:

```
cdcd77c0992ec5bbfc459984220f8c45084cc24d9b6efed1fae540db8de801d2
```

From My understanding the first 4 Bytes should be `cdcd`  and that is not correct. So then I found myself down a rabbit hole and attempted to do a text > ASCII > Keccak Signature and that still did not produce what I needed.. So I am asking the community to help me understand how 4 bytes have turned into 10 characters.... Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Response from every hashing function, like *keccak-256*, are bytes or hex string representing those bytes. Every byte is represented by 2 characters in hex string. So 4 first bytes are 8 first characters. In you example there are

```sh
['cd', 'cd', '77', 'c0']
```

To indicate that some string should be interpreted as a bytes, there are prefixed with `0x`.

When you combine those two rules you get `0xcdcd77c0` function selector.